# Reading serialised object in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Trying to read a object serialised and written to a file. The object is pretty big and was wondering if I can deserialise the data into an object with less complexity.

```
class BigObject extends Serializable{
 String a;
 String b;
 String c;
 String d;
 BigObject2 innerBigObject2;
 BigObject4 innerBigObject4;
 BigObject3 innerBigObject3;
 
//pseudo FileOutputStream.writeOutputObject(this)
//pseudo FileOutputStream.readInputObject(this)
}
```

Now can I read the data of a and b in Bigobject using the below class? Or the object to be deserialised has to be identical?

```
class SmallObject extends Serializable{
 String a;
 String b;
 
//pseudo FileOutputStream.writeOutputObject(this)
//pseudo FileOutputStream.readInputObject(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deserislize to a different class object using Java default serialization process. That is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can do this, but it is fairly tricky.  the serialized data contains the serialized class name.  in order to do what you want, you could compile a different version of BigObject *with the same class name and serialVersionUID* (but fewer member variables) and deserialize the data into this class.

however, if you want a single application with both versions of BigObject in it, then you need to start doing tricky things with classloaders.

One option here is to skip java serialization and use something more common (nowadays) like json.  there are plenty of json serialization frameworks which would easily allow you to serialize and deserialize using different classes (with different combinations of attributes).